# form submitting not refresing value if get out the button

Tags: html, css

I have a form, that I need my save button to be outside of form elements, but if I take it out elsewhere, it doesn`t like refresh the form.

```
<form  ng-submit="save()"  action="" name="addInv" novalidate>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newlocation.name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <label>Storage administrator:</label>
                    <select  ng-model="newlocation.administrator" class="form-control" ng-options="user.resource_uri as user.first_name for user in users"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Street:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newlocation.street" class="input-medium form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>City:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newlocation.city" class="input-medium form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Country:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newlocation.country" class="input-medium form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Postal code:</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="newlocation.postalCode" class="input-medium form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button class="btn tbn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

If I put button outside the `<form>` form doesn't refresh values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to do this

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" />
```